# C# convert object in a list to another object

Tags: c#

Is it possible to assign list of objects to another list of objects that takes it as a constructor?

Eg.

```
public class PersonORM{
    public PersonORM(Person p){ /* convert */ }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    /* Other properties here */
}

public class Person{        
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    /* Other properties here */
}
```

How do I convert `Person` to `PersonORM` using the constructor when they are in a list like this:

```
List<Person> people = getPeople();
List<PersonORM> peopleOrm = new List<Person>(people); // Is something like this possoble?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do that with the syntax you have as the constructor of `List<T>` does not support it.

If you can use linq (depending on which version of .Net you are targeting), you can do this:

```
List<PersonORM> personOrm = people.Select(p => new PersonORM(p)).ToList();
```

This uses the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) operator to perform the conversion from each item in the original list.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using LINQ:

```
List<PersonORM> peopleOrm = new List<Person>(people.Select(p => new PersonORM(p)));
```